# Drag and drop item in template_list?

Tags: scripting, interface

Is it possible to make items in a `template_list` draggable? (In order to rearrange them and such).

If not, is there any "workaround" or something?

Comment: Hello. there are very few instances in Blender where drag'n'drop is supported. The only ones that come to mind are color field values, asset browser, material slot items, outliner items and blender files. Template lists are not one of them I'm afraid.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help @Gorgious , and also for pointing the ones who support it (it may help me to re-think my system and come up with something )

Comment: Hehe happy to help. I don't think either of them fire callbacks that are available with the python API though